# Cancellation policy of 401 developer examination

Tags: dev401

I have registered 401 developer exam format as "Online Proctoring" instead of "Onsite Proctoring". I have opened a case in order to cancel the registration. My exam date is on 24-06-2015 and my case registered time was 07:43 PM ,20-06-2015. I need to know two things

1) When will this process get started and my registration get cancelled?
2) Will full of my amount be refunded?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. They will issue you a coupon code that you can use to re register for onsite proctoring.

Comment: May i know when will i get that coupon ?